# How do I install drivers for an AMD Radeon HD 6450?

Tags: hardware, drivers, ati

I bought new [computer](http://aldi.ie/ie/html/offers/special_buys3_15851.htm). The Graphics card is AMD Radeon HD 6450, on Windows 7 it works fine but I try to install driver on Ubuntu, and it says that "No supported adapters detected".  I downloaded the driver from [here](http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/linux/Pages/radeon_linux.aspx?type=2.4.1&product=2.4.1.3.42&lang=English). After installing "Aditional drivers" says that driver is installed. Also my screen resolution in Ubuntu is not maximum. Can you help me install proper driver, please? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the output from fglrxinfo, lshw -C video, and glxinfo? Verifying a proper install:
http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Verifying To install:
http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Category:Installation_Documentation

Comment: do you have "ATI catalyst control" in your preferences menu?

Comment: fglrxinfo = command not found

Comment: lshw -C video = 
*-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: ATI Technologies Inc
       vendor: ATI Technologies Inc
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=fglrx_pci latency=0
       resources: irq:18 memory:d0000000-dfffffff memory:fe9e0000-fe9fffff ioport:d000(size=256) memory:fe9c0000-fe9dffff

Comment: glxinfo = name of display: :0.0
X Error of failed request:  BadRequest (invalid request code or no such operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  136 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  19 (X_GLXQueryServerString)
  Serial number of failed request:  14
  Current serial number in output stream:  14

Comment: Yes I do if I install proprietary driver.

Comment: From your comments in other answers, it sounds like you've tried to install the 64 bit version of the binary driver on a 32 bit OS install. If your CPU is 64bit `cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep "lm"` install 64bit OS. If not, use the 32 bit binary driver.

Comment: But driver is for x64 and x32. If I install x64 is that would help?

Comment: I installed Ubuntu x64 and then install the driver... Driver does not work...

Comment: @vanysha Please add this information to your original question so it doesn't get buried in the comments.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem, but it worked fine for the previous version of this driver: "AMD Catalyst™ 11.8 Proprietary Linux x86 Display Driver". Here are the steps to download and install it:

- Download the AMD Catalyst™ 11.8 Proprietary Linux x86 Display Driver

  ```
   wget http://www2.ati.com/drivers/linux/ati-driver-installer-11-8-x86.x86_64.run
  ```

  If you don't have 'wget', install it by

  ```
   sudo apt-get install wget
  ```
- Make it executable, if not already

  ```
   chmod +x ati-driver-installer-11-8-x86.x86_64.run
  ```
- Run it and follow on-screen instructions to install the driver

  ```
   sudo ./ati-driver-installer-11-8-x86.x86_64.run
  ```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

- Do it in Debian mode:

  ```
  sudo aptitude install xserver-xorg-video-ati
  ```
- Or download the generic driver here:

> http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/Pages/index.aspx

Then go to another console (CTRL+ALT+F2), log in as root, shut down X (`/etc/init.d/gdm stop`), install the driver, and restart your box.

Comment: Nothing changed... Catalist control center does not work.

Comment: Is your box 32-bit or 64-bit? Please post the result of:`sudo lspci | grep VGA`.

Comment: My Ubuntu is installed from the original CD that Canonical send to me, so it's x32.
sudo lspci | grep VGA =
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: ATI Technologies Inc Device 6779

Comment: Remove the current installed driver firstly: `sudo aptitude remove xserver-xorg-video-ati`. And then install the generic driver. You had better do them after shutting down X: `sudo /etc/init.d/gdm stop` (if you use gnome).

Comment: I done exactly the same... The driver does not work.

Comment: You should recommend xserver-xorg-video-radeon instead, as that's the driver AMD is working on, and it's quite a bit better than *-ati.

Answer (score 1):

You should say which version of Ubuntu you're using. In 11.04, the open radeon driver should work well, though not perfectly. In 11.10, it's been improved further, and I much prefer it to the proprietary driver for my HD 5850. It's faster and it's easier to deal with.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and also another one that you seem to also have at the same time: a big annoying [AMD Unsupported Harware](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25519/how-to-remove-amd-unsupported-hardware-without-reinstalling-the-driver) icon. As a consequence, when I tried to install Ubuntu 10.10, it froze just after the login screen and when I tried to install Ubuntu 11.10, it did not even arrive to the login screen.

Here is what I did, which solved the problem:

- using another computer, download the latest proprietary driver from ATI on the official site. In my case I had to download it from [here](http://support.amd.com/fr/gpudownload/linux/Pages/radeon_linux.aspx?type=2.4.1&product=2.4.1.3.42&lang=English).
- put the driver on a USB key
- reboot the computer we want to repair
- in the grub menu, select the recovery mode. This results in arriving at a command line interface. This is a proof that the Ubuntu operating system is functioning but that the problem is indeed the graphical card.
- uninstall all previous versions of `flgrx` by launching `sudo apt-get remove flgrx` for example
- mount the USB key with something close to `mkdir /mnt/usb` followed by `sudo mount /dev/sdb /mnt/usb`. Another way for this little step is explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/45241/mount-drive-through-command-line-as-if-i-clicked-on-it-in-nautilus).
- use the `cd` command to place yourself in the folder where the downloaded driver is
- if necessary, make the driver be executable with something like `chmod +x ./ati-driver-installer-11-11-x86.x86_64.run`
- execute the driver using `sudo ./ati-driver-installer-11-11-x86.x86_64.run`
- follow the instructions given on the installer
- if this step did not work, you may want to try `sudo ./ati-driver-installer-11-11-x86.x86_64.run --force` instead
- reboot your computer

Then your two problems should both be solved!

Answer (score 1):

Just managed to get the above card to work on my device, running `12.04`, 64-bit. I started by following the suggestions here, none of which appeared to work in my case.

The device already had a video card (Matrox VGA) which was working fine. Wanted to add this to support dual monitors. When I added the AMD Radeon HD 6450 then I would get a blank screen. (Output from the Radeon was colored pixels with no sign of response from keyboard). I would bypass the blank screen with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F2</kbd> to get a terminal up, which displayed as expected.

Output from `fglrxinfo` was `command not found`.

The link referred to by vikram appears no longer to be working and has moved to that referred to by Agmenor. I followed those instructions and it told me install had completed, so rebooted and same situation as above.

Ultimately I followed the instructions [here on the Official Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/AMD#Installing_via_the_command_line) which I will repeat briefly. These were run line-by-line as `sudo`:

```
### backup configuration file
cp /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.BAK
### in case already installed
apt-get remove --purge fglrx fglrx-amdcccle fglrx-updates fglrx-amdcccle-updates
apt-get install -y fglrx fglrx-amdcccle
aticonfig --initial
reboot
### now check it's working
### connect video out to new video card
fglrxinfo
### add video acceleration
apt-get install -y xvba-va-driver libva-glx1 libva-egl1 vainfo
```

This is good enough for me. The boot output still goes to the Matrox and the Radeon output is blank until `X` starts.