# How-to remove "amd unsupported hardware" without reinstalling the driver?

Tags: drivers, ati

I installed driver from `Additional drivers`.... AMD Radeon HD 6450

My resolution is at maximum and Catalist Control Center is working but I have `AMD Unsupported hardware` image on the right bottom of my screen.  How can I remove it without reinstalling driver? Because the drivers from official amd site does not work.

[image]