# What does the AMD unsupported software message in the right corner mean?

Tags: macbook, ati

I know that [similar question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25519/how-to-remove-amd-unsupported-hardware-without-reinstalling-the-driver) was already asked but there are no information about how serious is this message. I mean, does it mean that my ATI 6750 card wasn't really recognized by proprietary driver or it is a bug? In the ubuntu [documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBookPro8-1/Natty) it is written that this card works from box. So I'm a bit confused. 
PS I installed "AMD/ATI FGLRX proprietary graphic driver" but I can't install "AMD/ATI FGLRX proprietary graphic driver(post release updates)". It returns error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Unsupported Hardware Watermark

This can happen if your card's PCI ID wasn't officially certified to work with a particular version of Catalyst. It does not necessarily mean that your card is unsupported, but it does mean that you shouldn't file bugs with that particular card/driver combination. If you installed the driver by downloading it from AMD/ATI, installing a newer version of Catalyst will probably help.

If you installed the proprietary driver included with Ubuntu or you do not want to upgrade to a newer version, it may be possible to work around the issue by using a control file from a newer version of Catalyst than the one you're running.

```
cd ~/; mkdir catalyst11.10; cd catalyst11.10/
wget http://www2.ati.com/drivers/linux/ati-driver-installer-11-10-x86.x86_64.run
chmod +x ati-driver-installer-11-10-x86.x86_64.run
sh ati-driver-installer-11-10-x86.x86_64.run --extract driver
sudo mv /etc/ati/control ~/control.bak
sudo cp driver/common/etc/ati/control /etc/ati
```