# "AMD unsupported hardware" error message is displayed

Tags: drivers, ati

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How-to remove “amd unsupported hardware” without reinstalling the driver?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25519/how-to-remove-amd-unsupported-hardware-without-reinstalling-the-driver)

I have a SAMSUNG 305U1A Netbook and just installed the AMD/ATI generic driver for my   AMD Radeon HD 6320 Rebooted my PC And A little box "AMD Unsupported hardware"

Comment: Which driver did you install and from where?

Comment: This wiki has great information on ATI drivers - http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Hardware In my experience , if your card is not listed as supported (and yours is not on the list) it will be difficult to impossible to get working. Hopefully someone with more ATI experience then I can help you.

Comment: Even with the warning your card might just work normally but you need to create a `xorg.conf` file your self (or copy one that has general options) but it is important to know which driver version you installed and from where.

Answer (score 1):

Try the ATI/binary driver.

Instruction from Ubuntu [Here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/ATI)

By default Ubuntu will use the open source ATI or Radeon driver for cards manufactured by AMD/ATI. Some users however prefer the proprietary fglrx driver for various reasons.

The instructions on this page will tell you how to use this driver. If you encounter bugs with these closed-source drivers, developers will not be willing or even able to assist you in resolving your issues. Use them at your own risk. We encourage our users to prefer open source drivers.