# Mount drive through command line (as if I clicked on it in nautilus)

Tags: command-line, mount

I'm writing a backup script in which I need to mount a drive in the media bay of my laptop.

I know that I can get the job done by messing with fstab and the mount command. Perhaps that's the easiest way. Anyway, I'm interested in the following:

1. Initially the media bay drive is unmounted.
2. I click on the drive in the side-panel in a nautilus window and the drive is mounted.
3. I can access it at `/media/baydrive`.

---

**My question:**

Is there an easy way of performing step 2 from the command line? I.e., mount the drive to `/media/<device name>` without messing with `fstab`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try `udisks --mount <device name>`

To mount by partition label, you can do

```
udisks --mount /dev/disk/by-label/baydrive
```

Comment: Nice command, but I get `Cannot stat device file baydrive: No such file or directory`

Comment: The device name needs to be the device file used for the baydrive - something like /dev/sdb1

Comment: Right. Then it works. You know of any way of referring to just `baydrive` instead?

Comment: No. But if the partion has a label "baydrive" you can use `/dev/disk/by-label/baydrive`

Comment: whoaa,. I had no idea about that. great! Edited post to include this variant

Comment: udisks: command not found. Ubuntu 21.10.

Answer (score 6):

The most equivalent (at least for ubuntu 14.4) is

```
udisksctl mount --block-device /dev/disk/by-label/baydrive
udisksctl unmount --block-device /dev/disk/by-label/baydrive
```

The difference between `udisks` and `udisksctl` is that `udisks` always mount under /media, while `udisksctl` mount where nautilus would, which is sometimes `/media/${USER}`

Answer (score 2):

If you want this to be for your user and not root try this

```
udisksctl mount -b /dev/sdb2
```

use the right name of your disk

Answer (score 0):

automounted drives

```
/media/username/driveUUID/
```

nautilus samba mounted drives are found in

```
/run/user/1000/gvfs/smb-share:server=10.100.4.16,share=share-name/path-to-folder/
```

or for sftp mounts you can access at

```
/run/usr/1000/gvfs/sftp\:host\=10.100.4.16/
```

Answer (score -1):

You can alternatively mount the drive, it will then appear at the side panel.. you can right click that shortcut on the side panel and lock it on the launcher.. now you will be able to simply single click that icon to mount the drive without any command, startup script or opening nautilus.

Comment: The whole point of the question is how to do this *without* fiddling with the GUI. I want to put the backup script as a cron job.