# How to remove the “AMD Testing use only” watermark?

Tags: ati

I've installed the [latest catalyst driver](http://www2.ati.com/drivers/beta/amd-driver-installer-catalyst-12.11-beta-x86.x86_64.zip) `(beta)` following the step in [this guide](http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Quantal_Installation_Guide) for Ubuntu **Quantal Quetzal**.
**My system is 64 bit** and my graphic card is an ATI RadeonHD 6670, this g.c. is **Officially Supported** (Catalyst & Open Source), you can confirm that from this [AMD Linux Community thread](http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Hardware#Not_Yet_Supported_or_Unoffically_Supported).

I don't have any problem, except the `AMD testing use only` watermark. I see the following frame in any stage into the OS (logged, unlloged, etc.) except in the terminals.

[image: IMG0]
[image: IMG1]

I found different versions of how to remove this image, but this change according to the system, so I want an answer from this popular (trusted) site.

- How to solve this issue in Ubuntu 12.10 32b?
- This procedure is different in a 64b system?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

## For Ubuntu 12.10 64-bits

I fixed it using the following script. Found At: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2076381

Under **Ubuntu 12.10 x64** and driver AMD `12.11` beta.

```sh
#!/bin/sh
DRIVER=/usr/lib/fglrx/xorg/modules/drivers/fglrx_drv.so
echo "Come on AMD!"
echo "Removing AMD logo from "$DRIVER
for x in $(objdump -d $DRIVER|awk '/call/&&/EnableLogo/{print "\\x"$2"\\x"$3"\\x"$4"\\x"$5"\\x"$6}'); do
    sed -i "s/$x/\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90/g" $DRIVER
done
echo "Reboot computer to finish"
```

Copy and paste the code from above into a new file, save it, and do `sudo bash filename` in the terminal.

Comment: Your system is the same that mine *(software)*. So it should work. The problem is that I need to be member of the **Ubuntu Forums** to download the file. Could you past the code here or in [Paste Ubuntu](http://paste.ubuntu.com/) and link it?

Comment: This is the direct download(of course use at own risk): http://paste.ubuntu.com/1322981/

Comment: Please tell me **how did you launch the file**. I saved the code in a file, but I can't launch it with the `sudo ./file` command.

Comment: @Lucio:  You need to mark the file executable to launch it that way.  Use `chmod +x file` to set the executable flag.  Alternatively, just launch it with `sudo bash file`.  Also, I feel compelled to point out that that script does *exactly* the same hackery as the one I pointed to.

Comment: Your right. The `bash` command worked perfectly.

Comment: This script no longer appears to work with version 13.3 beta drivers. `/usr/lib/fglrx/xorg/modules/drivers/fglrx_drv.so` is no longer present.

Comment: i had a similar problem. My little message didn't mention testing use though. Going into "Software and Updates" and the "Additional Drivers" tab and then setting the "X.Org X Server" radio got rid of my message after a reboot.

Comment: To all concerned parties, I added a bounty to solve this for blob users.  Setting it to Xorg is just disabling the testing driver and using the open one or the base non-testing one as far as I know.

Comment: It works on Elementary Luna as well.

Answer (score 52):

The script above did not work for me.
However I found a much simpler answer [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2074962)

Edit the ati signature file:

```
sudo gedit /etc/ati/signature
```

and just replace the "UNSIGNED" line with the following code

```
9777c589791007f4aeef06c922ad54a2:ae59f5b9572136d99fdd36f0109d358fa643f2bd4a2644d9efbb4fe91a9f6590a145:f612f0b01f2565cd9bd834f8119b309bae11a1ed4a2661c49fdf3fad11986cc4f641f1ba1f2265909a8e34ff1699309bf211a7eb4d7662cd9f8e3faf14986d92f646f1bc
```

It worked fine for me.

The resulting file should be 238 bytes long for it to work.

Comment: This fix didn't work for me at first, then I realized I added a trailing space at the end of the line, and a newline at the end of the file. Be sure the file has ONLY a single line with the signature and NO whitespace for it to work.

Answer (score 10):

## For Ubuntu 11.04

I found this elsewhere on the net and I ran it on a Ubuntu 11.04 - it works great!

http://phoronix.com/forums/showthread.php?19875-Unsupported-Hardware-watermark

Put this in a text file and save it (call it `fixwatermark.sh`):

```
#!/bin/sh
DRIVER=/usr/lib/fglrx/xorg/modules/drivers/fglrx_drv.so
for x in $(objdump -d $DRIVER|awk '/call/&&/EnableLogo/{print "\\x"$2"\\x"$3"\\x"$4"\\x"$5"\\x"$6}'); do
sed -i "s/$x/\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90/g" $DRIVER
done
```

With terminal go to the location where you saved it and do a

```
chmod +x fixwatermark.sh
```

to make it executable and a

```
sudo ./fixwatermark.sh
```

to let the script remove the `enableLogo`

Comment: It worked for me on 13.04 but I had to reboot.

Answer (score 2):

## For Ubuntu 12.10 64-bits

Running this script worked for me on Ubuntu 12.10 64bit:

```
#!/bin/sh
DRIVER=/usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fglrx_drv.so
for x in $(objdump -d $DRIVER|awk '/call/&&/EnableLogo/{print "\\x"$2"\\x"$3"\\x"$4"\\x"$5"\\x"$6}'); do
sed -i "s/$x/\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90/g" $DRIVER
done
```

One way to accomplish this:

1. Open a terminal
2. Type 'nano'
3. Paste the above code in to the editor
4. Control-x, Y to save
5. Enter a filename (I used 'logo.sh') and enter to return to the command line
6. `chmod a+x logo.sh` to make the script executable
7. `sudo ./logo.sh`
8. `sudo reboot`

No more logo after reboot for me.

Answer (score 2):

The correct solution has been published on the [unoffiical wiki page for AMD GPU Linux drivers](http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Maverick_Installation_Guide#Unsupported_Hardware_Watermark). The signatures for the latest GPUs are available only in the latest drivers. When using an old driver, there are no signatures for the newer GPU present in the computer. The solution, as given in the wiki, is to simply copy the control file of the latest driver and put them in your computer's ATI driver directory.

Here is what you do: Download the latest driver, extract it, copy the etc/ati/control file, and overwrite the /etc/ati/control file. The steps to follow are as follows:

```
$ cd ~ 
$ mkdir amd-gpu-driver 
$ cd amd-gpu-driver/ 
$ wget http:amd-website-linux-gpu-driver-url-amd-driver.zip 
$ tar -xvf amd-driver.zip 
$ sh amd-driver.run --extract driver 
$ sudo mv /etc/ati/control ./control.bak 
$ sudo cp driver/common/etc/ati/control /etc/ati
```

Please replace the URLs and filenames appropriately.

Comment: this is the real solution
patching logo calls from fglrx_drv.so -as described in above answers- only hide the watermark but you still have an "unsupported board" so aticonfig is unusable because "No supported adapters detected"

Answer (score 1):

I think this is caused by the modaliases that gets your pc to recognise your hardware.

When I have previously removed the ATI catayst application I have had to reinstall the fglrx-modaliases so that it can be installable through the additional drivers at a later stage.

So I would open a terminal up and enter

```
sudo apt-get remove fglrx-modaliases
```

This should not remove fglrx but just the modaliases

If there are problems after this obviously reinstall the modaliases

```
sudo apt-get install fglrx-modaliases
```

Comment: I get a `Virtual packages like 'fglrx-modaliases' can't be removed`  after issueing the `sudo apt-get remove fglrx-modaliases`.

Answer (score 1):

edit: sorry I missed the signature answer but did not want to keep this from people.

---

Get a copy of the `control` file from a release that does work for you and write it over  (you can extract the file from the tar.gz with fileroller)..

```
/usr/lib/fglrx/etc/ati/control
```

A reboot suffices.

Example from ...

http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/restricted/f/fglrx-installer/fglrx-installer_9.010.orig.tar.gz

[image]

[image]

Worked for me on 12.04, 12.10 and 13.04.

Comment: It worked for *what*? What does your method does? I'm missing the point here..

Comment: simple: you extract the file named "control" from the driver tar file version that did once did work and copy it over the one you are using now. After a reboot the image "AMD unsupported hardware" is gone.

Answer (score 1):

## For Ubuntu 13.04 64-bits

Since the latest drivers (13.4 and greater, not 12.11 beta as is in the question) the application will **automatically** remove the "AMD Testing Use Only" watermark during installation.

More about, including installation instructions: http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/linux/Pages/radeon_linux.aspx

Comment: I'm not voting since I can't test.  I'm depending on community and comments to make it happen one way or the other.

Comment: It appears to be removed from the just released 13.8 beta drivers. 13.6 still had it displaying (source: http://support.amd.com/us/kbarticles/Pages/AMDCatalyst13-8LINBetaDriver.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and also another one that you seem to also have at the same time: [not knowing how to install the right AMD Radeon HD 6450 driver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25321/how-do-i-install-drivers-for-an-amd-radeon-hd-6450/95575#95575). As a consequence, when I tried to install Ubuntu 10.10, it froze just after the login screen and when I tried to install Ubuntu 11.10, it did not even arrive to the login screen.

Here is what I did, which solved the problem:

- using another computer, download the latest proprietary driver from ATI on the official site. In my case I had to download it from [here](http://support.amd.com/fr/gpudownload/linux/Pages/radeon_linux.aspx?type=2.4.1&product=2.4.1.3.42&lang=English).
- put the driver on a USB key
- reboot the computer we want to repair
- in the grub menu, select the recovery mode. This results in arriving at a command line interface. This is a proof that the Ubuntu operating system is functioning but that the problem is indeed the graphical card.
- uninstall all previous versions of `flgrx` by launching `sudo apt-get remove flgrx` for example
- mount the USB key with something close to `mkdir /mnt/usb` followed by `sudo mount /dev/sdb /mnt/usb`. Another way for this little step is explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/45241/mount-drive-through-command-line-as-if-i-clicked-on-it-in-nautilus).
- use the `cd` command to place yourself in the folder where the downloaded driver is
- if necessary, make the driver be executable with something like `chmod +x ./ati-driver-installer-11-11-x86.x86_64.run`
- execute the driver using `sudo ./ati-driver-installer-11-11-x86.x86_64.run`
- follow the instructions given on the installer
- if this step did not work, you may want to try `sudo ./ati-driver-installer-11-11-x86.x86_64.run --force` instead
- reboot your computer

Then your two problems should both be solved!

Answer (score 0):

According to [the Arch Wiki's Catalyst page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/AMD_Catalyst), the following script should do it.  It's a bit hackish.

```
#!/bin/sh
DRIVER=/usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fglrx_drv.so
for x in $(objdump -d $DRIVER|awk '/call/&&/EnableLogo/{print "\\x"$2"\\x"$3"\\x"$4"\\x"$5"\\x"$6}'); do
 sed -i "s/$x/\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90/g" $DRIVER
done
```

Since that script is for Arch, you may need to play with bits of it; for example, Ubuntu may have fglrx_drv.so in a different location.  Be prepared to reinstall the driver from the command line if this doesn't work.

Comment: I don't want to *play with it* and see whats happens. I hope that someone that know exactly what do should I do, **without destabilizing the system**. Also, I have the `glrx_drv.so` file in this path: `/etc/alternatives/x86_64-linux-gnu_xorg_extra_modules/modules/drivers`

Comment: This does seem to be the most commonly accepted solution, and I haven't seen anyone complaining that it didn't work.  When I said "play with it" I mainly meant the path to the .so; clearly a little modification is necessary in your case ^_^