# No sound over HDMI 12.10 AMD A4 5300 APU MSI FM@-A55M-E33

Tags: sound, 12.10, hdmi

I just built a HTPC using an APU A4 5300 on a MSI FM@-A55M-E33 motherboard. I installed 12.10 and connected it through my TV. Video is fine but there is no sound. I checked the sound settings and there is no option for HDMI. I am using the recommended x-org driver. I tried fglrx and did a reboot but lost my desktop. I purged the fglrx driver and did a reboot and my desktop was restored. How can I get sound over HDMI?

- Adding `"radeon.audio=1"` in `/etc/default/grub` didn't help

Comment: To remove the watermark I found this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/206558/how-to-remove-the-amd-testing-use-only-watermark
It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the answer [here](http://www.unixmen.com/ubuntu-12-10-and-amd-catalyst-problem-solved/). I'm hoping for a better answer but the sound is working. The problem I have now is a watermark window in the right lower corner that says AMD unsupported hardware.

I can live with it for now but I hope it goes away with an update.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:makson96/fglrx
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install fglrx-legacy
```