# 12.10 Unable to install ATI drivers

Tags: 12.10, drivers, ati

I've tried for litterally hours to get my AMD ATI drivers installed. This seems to be a populair problem as it has been asked a lot here and I've tried everything I found. Nothing does it. Either I lose Unity completely, either I'm stuck with an inferior resolution and have no options to change it or I get a "For testing use only" watermark.

I've tried with the official drivers, both with the regular installation and by generating a .deb for my distribution. I've tried with an unofficial PPA available here. No chance.

Does any one have an idea how I can get this working?

Comment: To remove the watermark, http://askubuntu.com/questions/206558/how-to-remove-the-amd-testing-use-only-watermark

Answer (score 0):

I had a lot of difficulties getting it to work on my system as well.

There appear to be at least three different issues happening with the latest set of drivers.  They seem to be all intermingled on the [launchpad bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/fglrx/+bug/1068661/+index?comments=all).  These three situations are unsupported graphics cards, new (hybrid) graphics cards, and newly supported graphics cards.

In all cases you should remove any existing ATI graphics drivers (instructions from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-ati-catalyst-video-drivers-fglrx/129200#129200)

```
sudo sh /usr/share/ati/fglrx-uninstall.sh
sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx fglrx_* fglrx-amdcccle* fglrx-dev* xorg-driver-fglrx
```

If you have a AMD Radeon HD 2xxx-4xxx series card follow the [legacy installation instructions](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-install-amd-catalyst-legacy-drivers-in-ubuntu-12-10-quantal.html) to install from a PPA.

If you have a Hybrid graphics system (as I do) [these instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/205112/ubuntu-12-10-amd-intel-hybrid-graphics-not-working) might be helpful.

If you have a newly supported graphics card [try these instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-ati-catalyst-video-drivers-fglrx/129200#129200)

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for the late reply, I didn't receive any emails. Does the new version work any better?

Comment: I'm using version 13.012, it is quite stable. I tried the 13.013 beta drivers a few months ago. I had a SIGNIFICANT increase in framerate in Team Fortress 2 (as advertised in the driver's release notice), but my system was less stable and would sometimes hang. I'm back on 13.012 and probably staying here for a while.