# How to install AMD Proprietary driver correctly on ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: boot-failure

I would like to install AMD driver, however, I'm afraid because of past experiences after installing proprietary driver from Additional drivers. Everytime I installed be it ubuntu 11.04 or 12.04, After rebooting, I get a blank screen, and don't know how to get back.

Can anyone tell me, how to recover from a blank screen after installing AMD driver if i get so?

Thanks.

Comment: Follow this link.Download 12.11 driver that is the beta version of the driver. http://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-ati-catalyst-video-drivers-fglrx

Answer (score 0):

You will find a great article in [this Wiki Guide](http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Quantal_Installation_Guide) with recommendations, issues troubleshooting, and more.

I'll recommend you *(from my own experience)* to [install the latest Catalyst Diver manually](http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Quantal_Installation_Guide#Installing_Catalyst_Manually_.28from_AMD.2FATI.27s_site.29_BETA.2FEXPERIMENTAL). **I did followed the instruction mentioned in that link** and now my system is working like a charm.

- **My system:** `Ubuntu 12.10 64bits`
- **My graphic card:** `ATI RadeonHD 6670`
- **My driver:** `Catalyst 12.11 beta x86_64`

---

If you face trouble while installing, you should [Ask a new Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) in this site explaining the issue.

If after install the driver you see watermark, see [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/206558/62483) where you will find a solution.

NOTE: all the procedures that *you* do are at *your* own risk

Answer (score 0):

if you want to revert, all you have to do is right click anywhere in the blank screen and click on 'change desktop background. from there you go to click the all settings button on the far top left corner of the window. you either look for additional drivers or software source. if you go into software source, you will see a tab that says additional drivers on the far right top corner. in there you will see 3 video drivers. select and enable the one that says xorg. that is the one that works so far.