# Why does "AMD testing use only" pop up upon login?

Tags: drivers, ati, graphics, fglrx, opengl

I have just used this [website](http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Precise_Installation_Guide#Installing_Catalyst_Manually_.28from_AMD.2FATI.27s_site.29) to follow some of the steps to manually create the `.deb` file from the `.zip` file that is on the AMD site.
Then I installed them one by one using the *Debpackage* installer. So I didn't used the command line, but the graphical interface of my OS.

The problem is that when I log in I get this message: "AMD Testing use only"

Here is my `fglrxinfo`:

```
:~$ fglrxinfo
display: :0  screen: 0
OpenGL vendor string: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: AMD Radeon HD 6500M/5600/5700 Series
OpenGL version string: 4.2.12337 Compatibility Profile Context 9.01
```

Have I done something in the wrong way?

Comment: The "AMD Testing use only" watermark can be removed fairly simply, but before you go to the trouble of removing it, does the AMD watermark appear everywhere on your system after you have logged in?

Comment: You did nothing wrong. That is common after the installation of the proprietary drivers. See [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/206558/how-to-remove-the-amd-testing-use-only-watermark) to solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you installed the latest beta drivers from ATI instead of the stable ones, it is sometimes necessary to do so to make them work with some graphic cards and you should not worry.

To remove the watermark simply follow this post: [How to remove the “AMD Testing use only” watermark?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206558/how-to-remove-the-amd-testing-use-only-watermark).