# Xubuntu 13.04 HDMI sound Problem

Tags: sound, 64-bit, hdmi

I am having an issue with HDMI audio output with xubuntu 13.04. I did a clean install, downloaded updates after installation, am currently on *kernel 3.8.0-33-generic.* I have checked, and reloaded *alsamixer* and *pulseaudio*.

The pulseaudio shows that there is an output signal for HDMI but I have no sound. I cannot find any other helpful info.

I am new to xubuntu, is there anything that I have missed?

My desktop had an AMD a6 3620 APU.

Answer (score 0):

So if in Audio, Output you click on your HDMI output, you can't test it at all?

Try having a look [here](http://voices.canonical.com/david.henningsson/2012/04/14/audio-over-hdmi-and-displayport-in-ubuntu-12-04/)

even if the link is for a different version, the problme stills the same.
have a look the the first of comments about the command line to call the kernel..

Answer (score 0):

If you have a dedicated graphics card, HDMI is most probably controlled through that.

Check if you're using the default open source drivers or the proprietary ones (these usually have better hdni support, and generally are more performant). Use the 'lshw' to list your hardware devices.

Check these out if you're planning on installing these drivers:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/ATI

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia

Comment: I have installed the driver per the first link and everything seems to be working but I now have an icon in the bottom right corner of the screen that says "AMD Unsupported hardware". It cannot be opened. Is this normal?

Comment: No. It's not normal. Here is a question with a similar problem: http://askubuntu.com/questions/206558/how-to-remove-the-amd-testing-use-only-watermark