# Radeon r7 reported as hd 8600 "oland" on Ubuntu 12.04 with AMD proprietory driver

Tags: 12.04, radeon, fglrx, catalyst

Can anyone tell me why loaded latest fglrx Ati/AMD prorietory driver is identified as "oland" with Radeon HD 6800 VGA card (command: fglrxinfo); and also CCC identifies (catalyst 13.12 stable installed) my card as HD 8600 while my card is a Radeon r7 250? Since the drivers had worked (till the latest package update wrecked my GUI again ***), I tend to believe it is normal. Is it normal?

Comment: Not sure why it would say 6800. The R7 250 is based on the Oland chipset and is just a rebrand of the 8670. See: http://www.techpowerup.com/gpudb/2459/radeon-r7-250.html. Sure it's not 8600?

Comment: Ooops! My mistake: yes, HD 8600 of course. And thanks for the answer. (I also corrected the mistake in my original post)

Comment: Now my only remaining questions are:
#1 why jockey reports that my fglrx (proprietory) driver is activated but not in use? (other commands, eg. "lshw -c video" say it is in use) >> and indeed it must be;
#2 how the heck can i remove the "AMD unsupported hardware" watermark >> i know the thread + many many posts but no sure answer :-(

Comment: Have added an answer that hopefully covers everything. :)

Answer (score 0):

For the original question: The R7 250 is a rebranded HD 8670, based on the Oland chipset. That the driver still reports 8670 is not an issue.

For determining the driver in use, I use `lspci -v` and look for the "Kernel driver in use" in the "VGA compatible controller" section. I expect it will say fglrx in there, to confirm what lshw is saying.

To remove the beta watermark, I have found that this answer worked well: https://askubuntu.com/a/216730/121193.

Comment: First, thanks for the answers.
sudo 'lspci -v' reports that fglrx experimental is in use, indeed. However, method to remove the watermark doesn't work. There is the exact same content in the /etc/ati/signature file as I'm supposed to copy there...

Comment: Hmm, it worked for me, but it was a while ago. Each version of the drivers may need a unique magic number, so you may need to search with the driver version number?