# I'm having recurring problems with a driver install and think that there may be some corrupted/truncated files. How do I clear them?

Tags: drivers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install drivers for an AMD Radeon HD 6450?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25321/how-do-i-install-drivers-for-an-amd-radeon-hd-6450)

I'm running Ubuntu 11.10 x86 with PAE on GNOME3. I have a Radeon HD 5750, Phenom II 955, and 6GB of cheap DDR3. I want to install the newest version of the proprietary AMD driver for the GPU, however AMD's site is giving me some nonsense about a duplicate header and won't download the file. When using Ubuntu's built-in installer, there are two options: one with post-release updates and one without. The one without installs fine, but renders gnome-shell unreadable (applications work fine, interestingly). The version with updates, however, cuts off quickly and tells me to view /var/log/jockey.log. I have tried it more than a few times, and have rebooted multiple times. Is there a way to clear any caches? The program itself crashed the first time through, and I suspect that there might be some screwy files acting up.

[Here](http://minus.com/mbaONbxGYj#1) is jockey.log, in case that helps.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Give Ubuntu 15.04 a go ... use Dropbox to hold all cherished dirs to easily upgrade each release cycle ... graphic drivers are much better handled on recent releases

Answer (score 0):

I would install the driver manually.

1) Download from AMD: http://www2.ati.com/drivers/linux/amd-driver-installer-12-1-x86.x86_64.run

2) sudo apt-get --purge remove fglrx*

3) sudo sh amd-driver-installer-12-1-x86.x86_64.run --buildpkg Ubuntu/oneiric

4) sudo dpkg -i *.deb

5) sudo aticonfig --initial -f

6) reboot